# How to get class value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get class name of the component in html. I have code like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-content"><a class="label" onclick="getComponentId(this)" href="#">Open terminal</p></div>
```

And this is my code snippet:

```js
function getComponentId(el) {
  var componentId = el.id;
  var className = document.getElementsByClassName(el)
  alert(className)
  concatenateCredentials(credentials,componentId)
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content"><a class="label" onclick="getComponentId(this)" href="#">Open terminal</p></div>
```

I want to fetch class name "label". Above solution didn't work.

Comment: `el.className` should be sufficient

Comment: Unfortunately not. This solution don't give me any output alert.

Comment: You are retrieving the a node list of elements with that class name, not the class name itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply look at the `className` property on the element:

```js
function getComponentId(el) {
  console.log('className: ' + el.className);
}
```

```html
<a class="label" onclick="getComponentId(this)" href="#">Open terminal</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByClassName` returns an element from the class name.

You should be looking for `el.className` or `document.getElementById(el.id).classList`

Comment: I assume you meant `getElementsByClassName`? It's plural.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```js
function getComponentId(x) {
  var y = x.className;
  alert(y);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a class="label" onclick="getComponentId(this)" href="#">Open terminal</a>
</div>
```